# Weighted routing across multiple HAProxy backends

Tags: haproxy

I have two independent applications A and B. Each application uses blue/green deployments via blue/green AWS load balancers registered in a HAProxy backend using weighted routing.

I have the requirement to route traffic across *both* applications (backends) based on a weight, for example routing 90% of traffic to backend A and the remaining 10% to backend B.

Is it possible to set up a frontend in HAproxy that distributes traffic across multiple backends in the above way?

I considered putting all ALBs for both applications in a single backend but it then makes independently shifting traffic between blue/green of each application more complex.

Another option is to set up internal DNS for A backend and B backend and then the default backend can route between that but ideally I would avoid going "out" of HAProxy just to route back in.

Answer (score 3):

To selectively route identical requests to different "backends" (as defined by HAProxy -- server groups) you need some criterion that you can calculate in the frontend for each request -- and then `use_backend` when it's true (or false, as the case may be).

For example, the [`rand()` fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.2-rand) returns a random integer (not random in the cryptographic sense but random enough for this purpose) and the [`mod()` converter](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.1-mod) returns the result of modulo division, so if we want approximately 1:10 requests to go to backend `bbb` and the rest to go to backend `aaa` then we could do something like this:

```
frontend main
    mode http
    ...
    use_backend bbb if { rand(),mod(10) -m int 0 }
    default_backend aaa
```

Converters like `mod()` are preceded by their input so the output of `rand()` is the first input of `mod()` and the output of `mod()` is compared as an integer `-m int` against `0`.  If the random integer is evenly divisible by 10 then the expression is true and backend `bbb` is used.

You might further improve this by verifying that `bbb` has at least one healthy server before deciding to send it requests, by using the [`nbsrv()` fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.2-nbsrv) to insure that the number of healthy servers in `bbb` is greater than 0.

```
use_backend bbb if { rand(),mod(10) -m int 0 } { nbsrv(bbb) gt 0 }
```

Note that the config parser requires each `{` and `}` to have whitespace before and after except at the end of a line.

Comment: `rand(),mod(10) -m int 0` can be simplified to `rand(10) -m int 0`.